# deleting useless columns and rows in csvfile and save using python

Tags: python, csv

Here's a sample csv file;

```
out_gate,uless_col,in_gate,n_con
p,x,x,1
p,x,y,1
p,x,z,1
a_a,u,b,1
a_a,s,b,3
a_b,e,a,2
a_b,l,c,4
a_c,e,a,5
a_c,s,b,5
a_c,s,b,3
a_c,c,a,4
a_d,o,c,2
a_d,l,c,3
a_d,m,b,2
p,y,x,1
p,y,y,1
p,y,z,3
```

I want to remove the useless columns (2nd column) and useless rows (first three and last three rows) and create a new csv file and then save this new one. and How can I deal with the csv file that has more than 10 useless columns and useless rows?

(assuming useless rows are located only on the top or the bottom lines not scattered in the middle)

(and I am also assuming all the rows we want to use has its first element name starting with 'a_')

Can I get solution without using numpys or pandas as well? thanks!

Comment: Would you please elaborate whether it is possible to provide a solution with pandas and numpy or not.

Comment: I mean It would be better if I can get a solution without panda or numpy

Comment: If the file _"has more than 10 useless rows,"_ are they contiguous? If not, how are they designated?

Comment: I added a few supplementary assumptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have one or more unwanted columns and the wanted rows start with "a_".

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(reader)
    data = list(reader)

useless = set(['uless_col', 'n_con']) # Let's say there are 2 useless columns
mask, new_header = zip(*[(i,name) for i,name in enumerate(header) 
                          if name not in useless])
#(0,2) - column mask
#('out_gate', 'in_gate') - new column headers

new_data = [[row[i] for i in mask] for row in data] # Remove unwanted columns
new_data = [row for row in new_data if row[0].startswith("a_")] # Remove unwanted rows

with open('filename.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(new_header)
    writer.writerows(new_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution uses Pandas.

As the [pandas dataframe drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) function suggests, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("csv_name.csv")
df.drop(columns=['ulesscol'])
```

Above code is considering dropping columns, you can drop rows by index as:

```
df.drop([0, 1])
```

Alternatively, don't read in the column in the first place:

```
df = pd.read_csv("csv_name.csv",
                 usecols=["out_gate", "in_gate", "n_con"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv
data = list(csv.reader(open('filename.csv')))
header = [data[0][0]]+data[0][2:]
final_data = [[i[0]]+i[2:] for i in data[1:]][3:-3]
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
   write = csv.writer(f)
   write.writerows([header]+final_data)
```

Output:

```
out_gate,in_gate,n_con
a,b,1
a,b,3
b,a,2
b,c,4
c,a,5
c,b,5
c,b,3
c,a,4
d,c,2
d,c,3
d,b,2
```